# Eyedropper API working fine on Localhost but not working when I upload it on server

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making an image color picker and I have used Eyedropper API. It seems to work fine on localhost but I don't know what is the problem with it when I upload it on server.

```
if (!window.EyeDropper) {
            alert("Your browser does not support Image Color Picker feature");
        }

        const eyeDropper = new EyeDropper();
        const pickerBtn = document.querySelector(".open-picker");
        const toast = document.getElementById('toast');
        const result = document.querySelector(".color_code_field");

        function showToast(message) {
            toast.innerHTML = `
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff"
            class="toast_icon">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M9 12.75L11.25 15 15 9.75M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
        </svg>
        ${message}
        `;
            toast.classList.remove('hide');
            setTimeout(() => {
                toast.classList.add('hide');
            }, 3000);
        }

        imgInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
            const file = this.files[0];
            if (!file) return;

            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
                imgPreview.src = this.result;
            });

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

        pickerBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            eyeDropper
                .open()
                .then((res) => {
                    result.value = `${res.sRGBHex}`;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("User canceled the selection.");
                });
        });
```

when I run it, it gives me error in the console

`Uncaught ReferenceError: EyeDropper is not defined`

Comment: Are you opening the website while on the server with the same browser? This is only client side code, so there is no difference between using it from a server or from a local server (localhost)...

Comment: Do you serve your application over HTTPS? EyeDropper API only available over secure context. (Sometimes localhost becomes an exception to this)

Comment: My guess is as Yunus says, it's https - I can get it to work on my https hosted server but NOT on my http localhost